# How to implement PTZControl of an ip camera streaming in RTSP

Tags: php, rtsp, ip-camera

I am trying the below code for zoom and other ptzcontrols for an ip camera streaming using rtsp link.

```
curl -X PUT \
  http://admin:12345@103.124.172.70/PTZCtrl/channels/101/continuous \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/xml' \
  -H 'postman-token: 7623723a-ae45-f7d1-8073-ecf062fc8721' \
  -d '<PTZData version="2.0" xmlns="http://admin:12345@103.124.172.70">
   <zoom>1</zoom>
</PTZData>'
```

But i am getting below error:

```
401 Unauthorized
Your client does not have permission to get URL /PTZCtrl/channels/101/continuous from this server.
```

Comment: Are the credentials really correct? Maybe you have to create API specific credentials using the admin panel.

Comment: Got it we need to pass Authorisation header with username:password in base64 encryption.